# Convert for java loop to groovy

Tags: java, groovy

How can I convert this to 'groovyesque' code
I'm confused with the char value...Can't I just have a StringBuffer `def SB = "<<"` and `replaceAll()` function to accomplish the following

```
 static String stripSpaces(def str) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer()
    for (int i = 0 i < str.length() ++i) {
        char t = str.charAt(i)
        if (t == ' ') {
            continue
        }
        if (t == '.') {
            continue
        }
        b.append(t)
    }
     b.toString()
}
```

Comment: In Java: `return str.replaceAll("[ .]+", "")`. In Groovy: The same, optionally without the `return`.

Comment: @Andreas Do you need to escape the `.`?

Comment: @chrylis Not inside a character class.

Comment: @Andreas post that as an answer, and I'll vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In Java:*

```java
return str.replaceAll("[ .]+", "");
```

*In Groovy:*

The same, optionally without the `return`.

Comment: so essentially this code will do the for loop? without the Char literal?

Comment: This code will completely replace your function body, and give the same result